# EXTJS 3.2 editorgrid: How to set focus to next cell

Tags: extjs, extjs3

From a `combobox`, I get the value to (sat_beli,kon_beli,satuan), I want to set focus to next cell (start edit). Can U help please.

**Here is my code:**

```
{
    dataIndex: 'kode_sub',
    header: 'Kode Stock',
    width: 160,
    align: 'left',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combo',
        allowBlank: true,
        mode: 'local',
        store: ds_stock,
        selectOnFocus: true,
        listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
        typeAhead: true,
        displayField: 'kode_sub',
        itemSelector: 'div.column-center-akun',
        valueField: 'kode_sub',
        tpl: resultTpl_stock,
        listWidth: 600,
        lazyRender: true,
        listeners: {
            select: function (combo, e, rec) {
                var invoice = this.getValue();
                var index = this.getStore().findExact('kode_sub', invoice)
                var record = this.getStore().getAt(index);
                var processed1 = record.get('sat_beli');
                var processed2 = record.get('konv_beli');
                var processed3 = record.get('satuan');
                var oSM = gridDetail.getSelectionModel();
                var oGrid = Ext.getCmp('grid-Detail');
                oGrid.startEditing(oSM.getSelectedCell()[0], oSM.getSelectedCell()[1]);
                oGrid.getStore().getAt(oSM.getSelectedCell()[0]).set('sat_beli', processed1);
                oGrid.getStore().getAt(oSM.getSelectedCell()[0]).set('konv_beli', processed2);
                oGrid.getStore().getAt(oSM.getSelectedCell()[0]).set('satuan', processed3);
                oGrid.stopEditing(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: try with `nextSibling` method of component e.g. `combo.nextSibling().focus()`. Refer [nextSibling](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-nextSibling)

Comment: i have try that , but its still cant move the cursor focus